# Batch - Set /a "Missing Operator"

Tags: batch-file

How come when I do this in my game it works

```
set /a Monster=%random% * 2 / 32768 + 1
```

But this one doesn't
(Note: MHP = 10 and DamageDealt = 5)

```
set /a MHP=%MHP% - %DamageDealt%
```

And when I run the second one it says "Missing Operator".
But it only says it once if I run the thing twice...

Here's a bigger snippit:

```
:FightExplora
if %HP%=<0 goto GAMEOVERExplora
if %MHP%=<0 goto FightEndExplora
cls
echo HP: %HP%/%MaxHP%     Str: %Strength%     XP:%XP%/%LVUP%     LV: %LV%     
$%Money%
echo.
echo You encountered a %Monster%!
echo Monster -- HP: %MHP%/%MaxMHP%     Str: %MonsterSTR%
echo.
echo [1-Attack] [2-Heal]
set /p Action="What will you do? > "
echo.
if %Action%==1 (
set /a DamageDealt=%random% * %Strength% / 32768 + 1
set /a MHP=%MHP% - %DamageDealt%
echo You did %DamageDealt% to the %Monster%
goto EnemyTurnExplora
)
if %Action%==2 (
set /a HealAMT=%random% * %MaxHP% / 32768 + (%MaxHP% / %Strength%)
set HP=%HealAMT%
if %HP% => %MaxHP% set %HP%=%MaxHP%
echo You healed %HealAMT% HP
goto EnemyTurnExplora
)
:EnemyTurnExplora
echo.
pause >nul
::Enemy Damage
echo.
set /a DamageTaken=%random% * %MonsterSTR% / 32768 + 1
set /a HP=%HP% - %DamageTaken%
echo The %Monster% dealt %DamageTaken% to you.
echo.
pause >nul
goto FightExplora
```

Also, when you say to heal, then the command window closes and I don't know why...

Comment: There are many issues with your snippet, the main being that you should have previously enabled delayed expansion using `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and be referencing `%DamageDealt%` and `%HealAMT%` within your `if` blocks as `!DamageDealt!` and `!HealAMT!` respectively. Also try using GEQ and LEQ instead of the incorrect `=>` and `=<`

Answer (score 1):

Do not expand environment variables within an arithmetic expression using `%Variable%` syntax as this does not work within command blocks when the referenced environment variable is defined or modified within same command block. Also delayed expansion with reference syntax `!Variable!` is not needed within an arithmetic expression.

Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read carefully the output help explaining arithmetic expressions as well as delayed expansion. As you can read on studying the help you can simply use:

```
set /A MHP-=DamageDealt
```

> Any non-numeric strings in the expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are converted to numbers before using them. If an environment variable name is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value of zero is used. This allows you to do arithmetic with environment variable values without having to type all those % signs to get their values.

The reason for the error on using:

```
 set /a MHP=%MHP% - %DamageDealt%
```

Either environment variable `MHP` or `DamageDealt` or both were not defined on expanding the environment variables and the result was the execution of one of those 3 command lines:

```
 set /a MHP= - 50
 set /a MHP= 200 -
 set /a MHP= -
```

This can't happen with using:

```
set /A MHP=MHP - DamageDealt
set /A MHP-=DamageDealt
```

Each environment variable name on right side of the equal sign is replaced with 0 if the referenced environment variable does not exist at all on evaluation of the expression.